# List of IDs from associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I have 3 models: Users, Articles and Comments.

- Articel has many Comments.
- Comments belongs to Article.
- User has many comments.

Textbook case :)

I would like to make a list of Article IDs where the User has made Comments on. How do I do that?

I've tried variants of User.find(1).comments.articles_ids in the console but that gives me a undefined method error.

I'm sure it's simple, but I cant't figure it out :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing it, that works with your current setup:

```
user.comments.collect(&:article_id).uniq
```

Alternatively I guess you could add a `has_many :through` to `User`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles, :through => :comments
end
```

then you can get the ids via `user.articles.collect(&:id)` (perhaps also `user.article_ids`, but I'm not sure about that).

Comment: See.. I knew it was simple.. I went for the has_many :through solution and it worked like a charm with the user.artcles_ids.. Thanks man!

Comment: well.. it didn't work afterall.. Since User also has many Articles it gonna give me some issues.. But then I removed the has many through option and tried the user.comments.collect(&:article_id).uniq and that seems to work better and gives me no issues.. nice with answers with multiple options to choose from :)